# Python. Parse csv file. Append value to previous row if next row have duplicate value

Tags: python

I would like to use python to parse(transform) csv file.

Csv file inside:

```
AssetName, AssetTag
Laptop, 856231
Desktop, 665786
Desktop, 125548
Laptop, 657843
```

I need transform to:

```
AssetName, AssetTag
Laptop, 856231
Desktop, 665786, 125548
Laptop, 657843
```

Task - check if next row have the same "AssetName". If so - append "AssetTag" value to previous row.

For now I am not even sure if it is possible with Python Csv module. Dont know how to compare previous row with current row.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do show any code you have made to solve this problem.

Comment: Would you like to share some python code you've tried so far?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: Suggestion - pandas has a groupby operator

Comment: @AK47 they were not cobined as they are not con consecutive lines.

Comment: is there a change that there may be more than 2 desktop rows consecutively? for example, what if there are 5 desktop rows one after the other are you expecting all of these to be combined into a single line for desktop and 5 assetids?

Comment: In real file more than two consecutive lines might appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by simply parsing the file line by line and checking if the current `asset` is the same as the previous one.

First, let us store the assets and tags in a list inside `transformed_data`, to access tags easily, like so:

```
[ [ asset1, tag1 ], [ asset2, tag2 ], ... ]
```

Note that I assume the file contains *only* asset and tag in each row.

```
# Some constants to improve readability
ASSET_FIELD = 0
TAG_FIELD = 1
# Open the file to parse
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    transformed_data = list()
    # Skip the headers
    for line in csv_file.readlines()[1:]:
        # Extract the asset and its tag
        asset, tag = line.split()
        # if asset is same as last asset of transformed data, ie the previous asset read
        if transformed_data and transformed_data[-1][ASSET_FIELD] == asset:
            # Append to previous tag
            transformed_data[-1][TAG_FIELD] += ', ' + tag
        # Else, simply append it
        else:
            transformed_data.append([asset, tag])
```

And this gives:

```
[['Laptop,', '856231'], ['Desktop,', '665786, 125548'], ['Laptop,', '657843']]
```

Now, if we want, we can convert it back to a list of strings:

```
# Join each row into a string
transformed_data = [ ' '.join(row) for row in transformed_data]
print(transformed_data)
```

And, this shows:

```
['Laptop, 856231', 'Desktop, 665786, 125548', 'Laptop, 657843']
```

You can do whatever you want with it, and even write it back to the file. Remember to reattach the headers!

*Edit*: If you are getting `\n` in the strings, simply do:

```
# Join each row into a string
transformed_data = [ ' '.join(row).replace('\n','') for row in transformed_data]
print(transformed_data)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was watching on csv.DictReader.

Comment: @user12013825 If you had wanted to combine _all_ assets with same names together, then it would be useful. But here, you need to only combine consecutive assets.

Comment: After transformation I have got: "['Laptop,856231\n', 'Desktop,665786\n, 125548\n', 'Laptop,657843']".  I see '\n' . How to omit it ?

Comment: @user12013825 see edit.

Comment: ...replace('\n','').   Perfect! ))

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Jaideep Shekhar's answer I rewrote the script using `csv.DictReader` (As I was trying at the beginning).

```
# Create empty list
transformed_data = []
# Open the file to parse
with open('data-in.csv') as file:
 for row in csv.DictReader(file):
# if asset in current row is equal to last asset in transformed data
  if transformed_data and transformed_data[-1]['AssetName'] == row['AssetName']:
   transformed_data[-1]['AssetTag'] += ',' + row['AssetTag']
  else:
   transformed_data.append(row)
```

Nice decision to avoid "out of index" error. I did not guess.

```
transformed_data and transformed_data[-1][ASSET_FIELD]
```

Thanks everybody.